# sha-512 returning different value for same string

Tags: java, sha, sha512, tripledes

I am new to java security so it may sound stupid to you guys. I am using triple-des algorithm for encryption decryption in that i am using hash value as keys. I am using sha-512 for hashing i have heard that two same strings hash will be same but i am getting different output for same string. I am affixing the code of sha-512. Let me know what the problem is if possible.

```
public class SHA256Algo {

    public static String createHash(String text) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException 
    {
        String encryptedText = "" ;
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");

        md.update(text.getBytes("UTF-16")); // Change this to "UTF-16" if needed
        byte[] digest = md.digest();
        String str = digest.toString() ;
        return str ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println(createHash("tarun")) ;
            System.out.println(createHash("tarun")) ;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

output :
[B@32d2bb53
[B@29086036

Comment: toString() on array does not have the effect you expect.

Comment: Can you use third-party libraries?  This would be much simpler if you could use Guava's `Hashing.sha512().hashString(text, Charsets.UTF_16).toString()`, which would accomplish exactly what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays are objects too in Java, but they don't override `Object`'s `toString()` method.  The output is not the hashed output, but the result of [`Object`'s `toString()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--).

> [T]his method returns a string equal to the value of:

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

The `getClass().getName()` is responsible for `[B`, then there is the `@` character, and the rest of the characters are the hexadecimal hash code, also from `Object`.

You need to convert the `byte` array to a `String` in another way besides calling `toString()`.  This may involve conversion of the byte array to Base 64 or to hexadecimal characters.

Comment: thanks for your time can you give me a sample code to that particular conversion.

Comment: @tarunverma take a look at the Byte and String API for a method something like *parse* or *value*. Look at their javadoc. All of this should be easy if you have [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-developer.php) set up [nicely](http://superuser.com/questions/167458/how-to-add-javadocs-to-eclipse).

Comment: thanks all i found the way out to convert it to string i am sharing the code hope it helps others...
`byte[] digest = md.digest();
  StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
     for (int i=0;i<digest.length;i++) {
       hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & digest[i]));
     }
  
  return hexString.toString() ;`

Comment: That probably doesn't quite work, in that it'll trim leading zeroes?  `String.format("%02x", digest[i] & 0xFF)` would be more correct.